# Does PhoneGap / Cordova allow your application to have a custom UI interface when using the device's camera?

Tags: cordova

For example, native applications like Instagram have their own interface to take photos. Does PhoneGap / Cordova allow you to construct a similar interface?

Answer (score 5):

The cordova 'core' has a [camera.getPicture](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html) function that allows you to access the camera (across all platforms, iOS, Android ...). However, the UI for this action is platform specific. In other words, the way your application uses the camera will look different on each platform.

If you want to customise the camera experience you are going to have to write your own plugin. This involves writing a native implementation for each of the platforms you wish to cover, and also the JavaScript 'bindings' for your plugin.

At this point you start to loose many of the key advantages of using Cordova! Perhaps consider alternatives like Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'd just have to build you own Camera plugin.

Comment: OK. Is there anything special about this type of plugin? Would it be written in HTML, CSS, JS as well? Would this be a JavaScript plugin that would sit on top of whatever the device's camera is capturing, as when using an app like Instagram? Where in the Cordova application folder structure is it recommended this type of plugin live?

Comment: More than likely you'd need to implement your own native plugin for this type of functionality.

Answer (score -1):

As of my thoughts are.  Yes but that would require that you changed the core of phonegap.